# How to turn off antialiasing in Chaco plots

Tags: python, enthought, chaco

Chaco always plots lines antialiased, so the output normally looks nice and smooth:
[image]

But antialiasing takes time and makes real-time plotting much slower. In specific cases I still would like to have non-antialiased plots. I haven't found in docs anything related to this. Is it possible to turn off antialiasing and have fast ragged curves?

Answer (score 0):

Add the argument `antialias=False` to the plot (or similar) method call.

Comment: Have you really tried this? This was the first intuitive thing I tried, doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't try it on your code (which you didn't show), but yes I have, on http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/chaco_tutorial.html#application-oriented-plotting

Comment: I've just tried it with the that example code (writing 'plot.plot(("x", "y"), type="line", color="blue", antialias=False)', Chaco 4.5), but the result hasn't changed a bit.. I'm quite surprised that it worked in your case. Have no idea what I'm missing.

Comment: What's your OS? Are you running from within Canopy, or from the command line? If the latter, is the environment variable `ETS_TOOLKIT` set?

Comment: According to the Kiva documentation and source, `set_antialias` (which is called by Chaco) does not seem to be implemented for all platforms and all backends. The abstract method is implemented in `AbstractGraphicsContext` and the basic method is implemented in `GraphicsContextBase` at [link](https://github.com/enthought/enable/blob/85f9e90941e2e263599a26f28915d58d1c78dcb1/kiva/basecore2d.py#L256), which is up to the backend to support it. I can not find a good list of supported backends, so I'm not sure which support it, but your best bet is to try different backends to see which support it.